# Raphael JS collision detection with walls while dragging

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have the following code for dragging shapes in Raphael:

```
var start = function() {
        this.ox = 0;
        this.oy = 0;
        self.bringToFront();
    },
    move = function(dx, dy) {
        var a = self.getAngle(self.rotation),
            bb = self.shape.getBBox();

        switch(a){
            case 90:
                self.shape.translate(dy - this.ox, this.oy - dx);
                this.ox = dy;
                this.oy = dx;
                break;
            case 180:
                self.shape.translate(this.ox - dx, this.oy - dy);
                this.ox = dx;
                this.oy = dy;
                break;
            case 270:
                self.shape.translate(this.ox - dy, dx - this.oy);
                this.ox = dy;
                this.oy = dx;
                break;
            default:
                self.shape.translate(dx - this.ox, dy - this.oy);
                this.ox = dx;
                this.oy = dy;
        }
    },
    end = function() {
    };
```

(`self.shape` is a Raphael set of paths and rects)

**I am trying to get it so you can't drag shapes out of the SVG canvas area.** Right now I am able to get the coordinates of the bounding box of the shape, `bb` variable in the `move` function. I tried to add a check for `if(bb.x < 10)...` but I don't know how to set the constraint to say: "Don't let it move any further to the left". Is it a problem that I'm checking the position of `x` for the bounding box but then trying to constrain the `x` position of the shape?

Comment: this didn't work? `if ( bb.x < 10 ) bb.x = 10`

Comment: Nope. I am using the x on the bounding box to check for position but I'm translating the shape's x, y. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer per se, but should point you in the right direction.

check out the raphael 2.0 reference for [drag](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.drag)

The image beside it is doing pretty much exactly what you require. The code behind it is in the [reference.js](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.js) file. If you search for "Element.drag-extra", you'll see this piece of code

```
(function (r) {
    var x, y;
    r.circle(15, 15, 10).attr(fill).drag(function (dx, dy) {
        this.attr({
            cx: Math.min(Math.max(x + dx, 15), 85),
            cy: Math.min(Math.max(y + dy, 15), 85)
        });
    }, function () {
        x = this.attr("cx");
        y = this.attr("cy");
    });

})(prepare("Element.drag-extra"));
```

Here, Dmitry is constraining the drag between a min of 15 and a max of 85 px. It should be possible to use a little DOM magic to find the size of the canvas and modify the above code accordingly.

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: why '15' and '85'? i can kind of see why '15' but '85' seems like it comes out of nowhere

Comment: because the box is 100x100, and the circle has a radius of 15. You always move the centre of the circle, thus the minimum position of the centre is 0+radius (15), and the maximum is 100-radius (85). Simple really.

Comment: `code r.circle(15, 15, 10)` you have the radius set to 10.  details are everything

Comment: The point still stands. 15 and 85 constrain the circle within the square. Were I to go back and look at it again, I might have decided to constrain to 10, 90. Seriously, that was a pretty trite comment considering I was trying to help.

Comment: without the correct radius of your circle the logic of your constraint settings becomes unclear.  all you had to do was fix your original answer